# NPAPI: modify plugin object's CSS properties

Tags: javascript, c++, dom, npapi, browser-plugin

I'm programming an NPAPI plugin for an embedded browser based on WebKit. One of the objects handled by this plugin is a video frame that I want to be resizeable through its javascript properties, `width` and `height`.

So, in my C++ implementation of the plugin, I expose these two properties (*width* and *height*) via the NPAPI [NP_Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPClass) function pointers (which map to *HasProperty* / *GetProperty* / *SetProperty* methods in my case).

Now, what bothers me is that when the Javascript in the webpage doesn something like this:

```
<object id="video" type="video/myPluginMimeType" style="height:150px;"></object>
<script>
var video = $('video');
video.height = 250; // all happens here
</script>
```

It successfully goes into my C++ code an performs the video resizing (in my embedded platform, it goes directly to the video driver).
**BUT**, right after that, I get called by the browser through the [NPN_setWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPP_SetWindow) function, giving me back the original dimensions of the video object (150px heightin this example).

Since this `NPP_setWindow` is also directly mapped to the video driver, I only see my video with 250px height during the blink of an eye.
I suspect this is all due to the browser taking only the original "style" attributes as the ones that count.

So, questions:

- Can I make the browser update its width/height (even *style*?) properties somehow through the NPAPI?
- Should I simply ignore the NPP_setWindow calls and perform the resizing uniquely based on the initial call to NPN_New() (which gives me the style properties of the object) and subsequent calls to `video.height` through the NP API?

I admit I'd prefer the first version, since it lets the browser decide when to redraw and this way I can have a pretty much stateless video plugin.
Also, this first version gives the webpage the ability to change the CSS properties of the plugin DOM object, which will automatically be reflected through the NPP_setWindow call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution(s), so I'll leave this here for other guys:

1. I set the width in aboslut values ( `object.style.width = 150;` ) instead of using a length value (as stated here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/ ). The correct javascript code needed to be like this: `object.style.width = 150 + "px"; // or "150px" directly`
2. Overall, my real problem was that I didn't know how to affect my object's CSS properties *from* the plugin C++ code. 
   I found the solution [here](http://markmail.org/message/no4qljdzmcvtrmn2#query%3a+page:1+mid%3am4aygkk56hv5dhbl+state%3aresults): you have to use NPN_GetValue( my object ) / NPN_GetProperty( "style" on my object) / NPN_SetProperty( "width" on the style property) to do that.

Comment: Honestly, though, I've found your best bet is to leave the object tag itself at 100%, 100% and modify the containing div; that way you're less likely to run into conflicts with your plugin object itself.

Comment: Yes, that what I thought, but I have no control on how people will use my plugin object. Some of them might want to tinker with the CSS properties of the guy...

Comment: NPN_getProperty -> NPN_GetProperty; NPN_setProperty -> NPN_SetProperty;

Answer (score 2):

`<object>`s are HTML elements like any other; you can change their width and height with `element.style.width` and `element.style.height`. You should get an NPP_SetWindow call as soon as the dimensions change, so you don't need to hand-roll your own settable width and height properties.

Comment: That's where the problem is: when, say, I do this in JS: `element.style.height = 150;`, the browser looks for the `style` object in my NPAPI object. Since I didn't expose that property, it fails and I never see any NPP_setWindow call. The browser doesn't seem to make the difference between the CSS style properties and my object's properties.

Comment: See my answer (to my own question... I know): I failed to send the length in the correct format.